# How to send SendGrid email programmatically using a Design Library template

Tags: email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have an HTML design/template created in SendGrid's Design Library. How can I send an email in code (PHP in my case) using this html template? I have found [this line](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/examples/helpers/mail/example.php#L124) in SendGrid's sample code but not sure if this is the right direction or not. Any advice or pointers to documentation for doing this?

Comment: It's unlikely that people will want to type a whole tutorial here for you. See [ask].

Comment: I agree about the tutorial, but I don't think a tutorial is needed to answer this question.

Comment: Hey @Justin, did you try setting the template ID using the `setTemplateId` method and then sending the email? Did you find something didn't work?

Comment: @philnash I did try sending with the `setTemplateId` method set but that unfortunately didn't work

Comment: What do you mean that it didn't work? Can you share the code you used, what you expected to happen and what actually happened? (It is easier to edit your question with all that, then comment again to let me know.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a dynamic template based off of your Design in the Design Library

https://mc.sendgrid.com/dynamic-templates

Then you can send the email programatically following these instructions:

https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates